# Is $[0, 1]$ open and closed when considering it as a metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If I consider the metric space $([0, 1], d)$ where $d$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}$, is $[0, 1]$ then open as well as closed? Since e.g. for $0$, an open ball would be
\begin{align*}
B(0, \epsilon) = \{ \color{blue} {x \in [0, 1]}\color{black}\mid |x| < \epsilon\}
.\end{align*}
so we don't consider anything that would be to the left of $0$ if we were working in $\mathbb{R}$. Is this conclusion correct?

Comment: You're indeed correct. In fact, the whole space is always open and closed, as is the empty set.

Comment: Every topological space and hence all metric spaces themselves are both closed and open by definition.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot for the quick answers!

Comment: $[0,\frac12)$ is also an open ball in this space. Just as another example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is. More generally for any metric (or even topological) space X, it holds that X is closed and open. Your characterisation of the open ball is right as well